# Form returns 'IntegrityError'

Tags: geodjango

I'm trying to create a simple form useful for put a point on a map.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
from django.db import models

class AddPoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = geomodels.PointField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.gis import forms

from .models import AddPoint


class AddPointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "type": "text",
                "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
                }
            ),
        )
    point = forms.PointField(
        widget=forms.OSMWidget(
            attrs={
                'map_width': 800,
                'map_height': 250,
                'default_lat': 0,
                'default_lon': 0,
                'default_zoom': 2,
                }
            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = AddPoint
        fields = [
            'name',
            'point',
            ]
```

**views.py**

```
def addPointOnMap(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        geoform = AddPointForm(request.POST or None)
        if geoform.is_valid():
            new_point = geoform.save()
            return redirect('add_points_map')
    else:
        geoform = AddPointForm()
    context = {
        'geoform': geoform,
        }
    template = 'maps/editing/add_point.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The template is a simple `{{ geoform.as_p }}`

When I click on "Add point", on the template, I see this message:

> IntegrityError at /map/create/add-points/
>
> null value in column "geom" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: 
>   Failing row contains (3, test, null).

From a week a try to solve this without results and I've seen that there aren't similar problem online. How I can solve this?

**NB**: *If I use the admin panel I can add the points without problem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is this:

```
point = forms.PointField(...
```

This is the right way:

```
geom= forms.PointField(...
```